# JSF - No se cambiar el valor del Bean con h:input

Tags: jsf, primefaces, input

acudo a ustedes porque esta problema, he buscado y no encuentro una solución.
El problema es el siguiente, tengo un `<p:dialog id="userUpdateDlg"  widgetVar="UpdateUserDialog" header="Modificar usuario"  modal="true"  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">`

que activo por medio de  `<p:commandLink  actionListener="#{listuser.editUser(user)}" update=":userUpdateDlg" onclick="PF('UpdateUserDialog').initPosition();"  oncomplete="PF('UpdateUserDialog').show()" >`

La funcion del p:dialog es actualizar los valores de un objeto, pero al cambiar los valores del objeto por input, no se realiza el cambio se mantiene el valor que ya tiene.

En un principio al dar click al botón p:commandButton, no accedía al método, pero pude solucionar el problema o eso creo, pero ahora surgió este problema que no logro resolver.

Aquí esta el código de mi XML

```html
<ui:composition  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                     xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
                     xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                     xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            template="../../WEB-INF/TempleteAdmin.xhtml" >

        <!--SE REDEFINE LA SECCION DE HEADER DEL TEMPLATE PARA ACCEDER A DOS ARCHIVOS CSS-->
        <ui:define name="title">
            <title>Listar de usuarios</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/templateAdmin.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/Administrador/ListUser/listUser.css"/>
        </ui:define>

        <!--REDEFINIENDO LA SECCION DE BODY O CONTENT-->
        <ui:define name="body">

            <!--BOTON PARA AGREGAR NUEVO USUARIO-->
            <div id="optionsData">
                <h:form style="display: inline">
                <p:commandButton styleClass="btnAdd" value="Agregar usuario" actionListener="#{listuser.initUser()}" update=":userAddDlg" oncomplete="PF('addUserDialog').show();" />
                </h:form>

            </div>

            <!--SE INCLUYE EL ARCHIVO DE LA VENTANA MODAL PARA AGREGAR USUARIO-->
            <ui:include src="Modal_add_user.xhtml" />
            <div id="datos_table">

                <h:dataTable id="user_Data" styleClass="table_user" value="#{listuser.tuserregDtoList}" var="user" border="1" binding="#{listuser.myDataTable}" >

                    <!--DATOS DE USUARIOS-->

                    <!--EDITAR-->
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Editar</f:facet>
                        <p:commandLink  actionListener="#{listuser.editUser(user)}" update=":userUpdateDlg" onclick="PF('UpdateUserDialog').initPosition();"  oncomplete="PF('UpdateUserDialog').show()"  />
                            
                    </h:column>

                    <!--CEDULA-->
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Cedula</f:facet>
                        #{user.idenCard}
                    </h:column>

                    <!--NOMBRE-->
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Nombre</f:facet>
                        #{user.nameUser}<!--HAY QUE AGREGAR EL GET DEL ARRAY EN EL BEAN, PARA ACCEDER A LOS VALORES DE LOS OBJS DENTRO DE LIST-->
                    </h:column>

                    <!--APELLIDO-->
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Apellido</f:facet>
                        #{user.lastName}
                    </h:column>

                    <!--DIRECCION-->
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Direccion</f:facet>
                        #{user.idAddressId}
                    </h:column>

                    <!--E-MAIL-->
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">E-mail</f:facet>
                        #{user.email}
                    </h:column>

                    <!--CONTACTO-->
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Contacto</f:facet>
                        #{user.contact}
                    </h:column>





                   
                      

                </h:dataTable>

            </div>




            <!--SE INCLUYE EL ARCHIVO DE LA VENTANA MODAL PARA ACTUALIZAR USUARIO-->
         <ui:include src="Modal_update_user.xhtml" />





        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

Este es el codigo que esta dentro del modal

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:body>
    <ui:composition><!--AL COLOCAR COMPISITION, SE ASEGURA QUE AL HACER EL INCLUDE EN OTRO ARCHIVO SOLO SE AGREGGUE LOS TAGS ESCRITOS DENTRO DEL COMPOSITION-->
        <!--VENTANA MODAL PARA AGREGAR PERSONA-->
        <p:dialog id="userUpdateDlg"  widgetVar="UpdateUserDialog" header="Modificar usuario"  modal="true"  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
            <!--widgetVar: para poder referecniar el elemento(nombre), modal: para que se muestre encima de la pag HTML,
                       showEfect & hideEfecte: para que se oculte y muestre paulatinamente el dialog; rizable: para que no se pueda reajustar el tamaño del dialog -->

            <!--FORMULARIO DE ADD_USER-->
            <h:form id="updateUserFormDlg">
                <p:outputPanel id="userEditDetail">
                    <p:panelGrid id="displayEdit" columns="4"   columnClasses="label,value">

                        <h:outputText value="Cedula" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{listuser.userSelect.idenCard}" required="true" readonly="true"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Nombre" />
                        <h:inputText immediate="true" value="#{listuser.userSelect.nameUser}" required="true"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Apellido" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{listuser.userSelect.lastName}"  />

                        <h:outputText value="Contacto" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{listuser.userSelect.contact}" />

                        <h:outputText value="E-mail" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{listuser.userSelect.email}"  required="true" />

                        <h:outputText value="Contraseña" />
                        <h:inputSecret value="#{listuser.userSelect.pass}" required="true"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Direccion" />
                        <h:inputText  value="#{listuser.userSelect.idAddressId}" required="true"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Fecha de creacion" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{listuser.userSelect.fechaCreacion}" />

                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <p:commandButton value="Guardar cambios"  update=":user_Data" actionListener="#{listuser.updateUser()}" process="@this" oncomplete="PF('UpdateUserDialog').hide()" >
                                <!--update: para que se actualice la tabla de datos; oncomplete: se oculta el panel de dialogo-->

                            </p:commandButton>
                        </f:facet>


                    </p:panelGrid>

                </p:outputPanel>
            </h:form>

        </p:dialog>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Código de Bean

```js
@Named(value = "listuser")
@ViewScoped
public class ListUser implements Serializable {
    private static long serialVersionUID=1l;

    private static final Logger log= LogManager.getRootLogger();
    private List<TuserregDto> tuserregDtoList=new ArrayList<>();//SE ENCARGAR DE ALMACENAR LOS USUARIOS QUE SE TRAE DE LA BD
    private TuserregDto userSelect; //ALMACENAR LOS USUARIOS QUE SE VAN A  EDITAR O ELIMINAR
    
    public void editUser(TuserregDto userSelect){
        this.userSelect=userSelect;
    }


    /*
    * METODO QUE ACTUALIZA EL VALOR DEL USUARIO ELEGIDO PARA EDITAR
    * */
    public void updateUser(){
   
        TusuarioRegsService tusuarioRegsService=new TusuarioRegsServiceImplService().getTusuarioRegsServiceImplPort();
        boolean validate=tusuarioRegsService.updateUserReg(this.userSelect);
        if(validate){


            for(TuserregDto tuserregDto : this.tuserregDtoList){
                if(tuserregDto.getIdenCard().equals(this.userSelect.getIdenCard())){
                    tuserregDto=this.userSelect;
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.reInitUserSelec();

        }else {
            log.debug("ERROR UPDATE");
        }
        
    }
    
     public void reInitUserSelec(){
        this.userSelect=null;
        log.debug("DATOS DE OBJ USERSELECT VACIADOS");
    }
    
    public TuserregDto getUserSelect() {
        return userSelect;
    }

    public void setUserSelect(TuserregDto userSelect) {
        this.userSelect = userSelect;
    }
```

- **Probe usando el mismo dialog y obj para actualizar e insertar, pero
  tampoco soluciono mi problema.**
- **Use `immediate="true"` para los inputs y botones, y tampo soluciono
  mi problema.**
- **Intente quitando el otro modal y tampoco soluciono mi problema**
- **Intente colocar el codigo XML junto en el mismo archivo(sin usar include),y tampoco funciono**
  **Ojala y puedan darme una solución, gracias de antemano**

Comment: Encierra el datatable en un outputpanel y el update lo haces a este. No lo hagas al datatable. También podrías cambiar el div de datos_table por un outputPanel y hace el update a este.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich bueno, si hago un set en metodo si actualiza la tabla, pero yo quiero setearlo por medio del input, y es lo que no pasa, lo que escriba en el input no modifica el valor del atributo asignado

Comment: Le pusiste a l outputpanel como contenedor del datatable y el update del comando guardar del diálogo lo hiciste a ese outputpanel?

Comment: En el process del comando guardar no lo hagas a @this porque no viajarán los input has process=@form

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich puse el "proccess=@form, y el botón no entra al método de actionListener :( cambia los valores pero no entra al método, y si puse el outputpanel  e hice el update en esa etiqueta

Comment: Hubieras probado hacer el process por el ID del form `process="updateUserFormDlg" ` ¿Que versión de primefaces estás usando? Bueno al menos mi comentarios te dieron alguna pista. Raro que no funcione el @form y el actionListener.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich la versión de PF que uso 11, y también provee hacer el proccess  en el formulario completo y en el dialog, pero cuando lo hacía no accedía al método cuando hacía click en el botón

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Ahora si resolví mi problema de una forma que se me hace aceptable.
**Primero:** borre los eventos de 'keyup' y el 'proccess' de `<p:commandButton>`  que habia mencionado en el 'PRE EDIT '.
**Segundo:** Agregue un evento por ajax al boton, y asi fue como se soluciono todo.
**Código del Botón**

```js
<p:commandButton value = "Guardar cambios" update = ":panelData" oncomplete = "PF('UpdateUserDialog').hide()" >

  <f: ajax execute = ":updateUserFormDlg listener = "#{listuser.updateUser()}" / >
</p:commandButton>
```

**Pre edit** 
Resolví mi problema, pero no como quisiera, y parcialmente.
Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:
Al botón `p:commandxx` le agregue el atributo de proccess y el valor de este fue el siguiente:

```html
 <p:commandButton value="Guardar cambios"  update=":panelData" actionListener="#{listuser.updateUser()}" process="@this name lastName contact email"  oncomplete="PF('UpdateUserDialog').hide()" />
 <!--name lastname contact ...: son los id de los input-->
```

Agregue los Id de los inputs para que procesara tambien esto, pero proccess dejaba de funcionar cuando le agregaba mas de 5 valores.
Entonces la solucion a ese problema para los demas input que no pude agregar fue ponerle un evento por ajax de change, y solo con eso basta para que se modifique el valor, el codigo es el siguiente:

```html
 <p:password id="pass" value="#{listuser.userSelect.pass}" required="true">
                            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{listuser.updatePass()}" />
                        </p:password>
```

Incluso poniendo el método vacío funcionaba

```html
public void updatePass(){
        System.out.println("Valor de pass: "+this.userSelect.getPass()); //LA IMPRESION SOLO ESTA COMO PRUEBA LUEGO LA BORRARE
    }
```

Lo que no se es si eso no traerá otro problema en el funcionamiento, seguridad o procesos innecesarios que consumen recursos.